# RxJS, can't get pipe(toArray).subscribe to work

Tags: rxjs6

I am rather new to RxJS and was trying to figure out a simple pipe(toArray), but can't seem to make it work.  Every example I've seen suggests that this should work:

```
import {toArray} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {of} from 'rxjs';

it('observable should generate array of length 3', done=>{
    of(1,2,3).pipe(toArray).subscribe(val=> {
        expect(val.length).toBe(3);
        done();
    });
});
```

Yet, it simply throws an error '.subscribe is not a function'

package.json:

```
"rxjs": "^6.4.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, my mistake was that I was using .pipe(toArray), instead of .pipe(toArray())